# Convert list of integers to an integer python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of integers:

```
lists = [8,7,2]
```

I want it to be:

```
result = 872
```

I can do it in the following way:

```
result = 0
for count, i in enumerate(reversed(lists)):
    result += i*(10**count)
```

It works. but I think there should be another better and faster way. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this

```
int("".join(list(map(str,lists))))
```

map all the integers to strings then join them and conver them back to integer.

Comment: `int("".join(map (str, lists)))`

Answer (score 4):

You can also do

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: 10*x+y, (lists))
```

No need to convert to string and back.

(for the completeness sake) When list might contain numbers bigger than 9 you can do something more complicated but faster than converting to strings.

```
from functools import reduce
def combine(x,y):
    temp =y
    if (temp==0): 
        return x*10
    while(temp>0):
        x*=10
        temp//=10
    return x + y

reduce(combine,lists)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it's much better way

Comment: But it has limitation. If the length of list exceeds 9, it won't work

Comment: You mean if the number in list exceeds 9 ? right? I wasn't expecting that looking at the code you have provided in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was my fault, I didn't tell you this. But what you did, excellent. Someone might get help from your answer

Comment: Thanks @RafeeMuhammad for pointing out. I have updated. of course it doesn't look as neat but it sure is faster :)

Comment: Errors? which python version are you using?

Comment: I have updated to handle the case of having 0 in the array.. becomes more messy lol.

Answer (score 3):

You could also just skin the string:

```
lists=[8, 7, 2]
result = int((str(lists)).strip("[]").replace(", ",""))
```

Comment: I'd been bashing my head, trying to figure out why a single list item of `[1]` would not convert to a string then int... has to do with the brackets!  I'd vote this answer up a dozen times if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple way to do it using int, str and list comprehension.

```
lists = [8,7,2]
result = int("".join([str(l) for l in lists]))
```